# When receiving an incoming call, recorded video is corrupted and AVFoundation methods are giving errors

Tags: iphone, ios4, opengl-es, notifications, avcapturesession

I have a video recording app. Everything works fine. Except when a phone call is received while recording.

When a phone call is received, I try to end the recording, however, any of my calls to write to an AVAssetWriter are denied. audioWriterInput `appendSampleBuffer` returns no, `appendPixelBuffer` errors out. I try to call avAssetWriter `finishWriting` but that returns `AVAssetWriterStatusFailed`.

Nothing works, my video is corrupted because it seems that my usual methods to finish up a recording session are not being allowed once a call is received.

What could I listen for to properly end a recording session when a phone call is received? The only thing I can currently do is listen for `applicationWillResignActive` and stop everything, but that prevents recording while a user receives a text message, etc. which would make my app work differently than the native Camera app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Core Telephony](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html) framework, and specifically the `CTCallCenter` class. You can register an `callEventHandler` which is a block that accepts a `CTCall` object. This object describes the call state. Try to end recording when the call object indicates it's an incoming call.

Comment: Thanks. I'd look at that briefly, but thought it was a private api for some reason. I'll look again. Seems odd that calls should have their own notifications that don't comply with all the other AppDelegate notifications.

Comment: I successfully used the api, and sure enough, I get the callbacks as expected. However, all my AVFoundation calls are still getting messed up. I'm diving deeper into it now to see what the issue is.